# Disconnecting a MongoDB node and running on its own

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Can a shard node be taken out of a shard set and run on its own?

For example, where you have a specific customer for each shard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it’s possible. MongoDB "main" nodes don’t know about sharding. Only the router (and the config server) know. You can also connect to your node directly if you use the right host and port.

If the node is part of a **Replica Set** things look a bit differently though. In that case you have to restart the server without the **`--replSet`** option. But be careful that you don’t take down a `PRIMARY` node.